# create dataframe with outliers and then replace with nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to make a function to spot the columns with "100" in the header and replace the values in these columns with NaN depending on multiple criteria.
I also want in the function the value of the column "first_column" corresponding to the outlier.

For instance let's say I have a df where I want to replace all numbers that are above 100 or below 0 with NaN values :

I start with this dataframe:
[image]

```
  import pandas as pd
        
    data = {'first_column':  [product_name', 'product_name2', 'product_name3'],
                'second_column': ['first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value'],
                 'third_100':['89', '9', '589'],
                'fourth_100':['25', '1568200', '5''],
                }
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    print (df)
```

expected output:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: I see you have a habit of posting screenshots of dataframes. Rather than posting a screenshot, simply copy-paste the data frame itself into the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# get "100" columns and convert to integer
df2 = df.filter(like='100').astype(int)

# identify values <0 or >100
mask = (df2.lt(0)|df2.gt(100))

# mask them
out1 = df.mask(mask.reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value=False))

# get rows with at least one match
out2 = df.loc[mask.any(1), ['first_column']+list(df.filter(like='100'))]
```

output 1:

```
    first_column second_column third_100 fourth_100
0   product_name   first_value        89         25
1  product_name2  second_value         9        NaN
2  product_name3   third_value       NaN          5
```

output 2:

```
    first_column third_100 fourth_100
1  product_name2         9    1568200
2  product_name3       589          5
```